# How to zip all PHP files in my webspace using SSH

Tags: server

My hostmonster webspace account got deactivated because they found many malicious code in my files. The affected files include hundreds of PHP/JS/CSS/ files littered around in scores of folders. It will be very time consuming to inspect all those files one by one and remove the malicious code. So I am thinking to download all the files while pertaining their path, and then  hopefully on my local computer, I can remove malicious code by search and replace in NOTEPAD++. To do that, I think firstly I need to zip all the files using SSH.

I try to google the usage of zip command in SSH, but surprisingly  almost all the results are very very simple, only explaining how to use `zip -r` to compress everything. What I need to do is to zip all PHP files, all CSS files, all JS files, etc. I also try zip -? in SSH shell, the usage is like

```
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
```

and in the option list, `-i` is `include only the followin names`, so I write this command

```
zip -i *.php PHP.zip
```

but it doesn't work. It returns

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
```

I tried some other ways but none of them worked. So I have to ask it here. Any hints and directions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the destination file prior to the condition.

```
zip -r PHP.zip *.php
```

That should work fine for you and create a zip file with all .php files from your website.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried this command and it only zips .php file under current directory

Comment: If this works for some users but not others with .php files in the current directory, that's because bash is expanding "*.php*, substituting a list of all the .php files in the current directly before it's passed to zip. Instead, try quoting the *: `zip -r PHP.zip '*.php'`